# Gulp Node.js Istanbul Isparta

Tags: javascript, node.js, istanbul, isparta

I'm trying to get unit tests coverage with Istanbul and Isparta, and I'm having some trouble.

Actually, here's my gulp file tasks:

```
gulp.task('pre-test', ['default'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(istanbul({
      instrumenter: isparta.Instrumenter,
      includeUntested: true
    }))
    .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire());
});

gulp.task('test', ['pre-test'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/test/**/*.js')
    .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'spec'}))
    .pipe(istanbul.writeReports({}));
});
```

When I start the gulp "test" task, I have the following errors:

```
[08:34:17] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error in plugin 'gulp-istanbul'
Message:
    Unable to parse C:\projects\nodejs\mon-notaire\src\app\core\logger\concrete\ConsoleLogger.js

Line 1: Unexpected token

[08:34:17] Finished 'pre-test' after 2.11 s
[08:34:17] Starting 'test'...

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
C:\projects\nodejs\mon-notaire\src\test\core\TestConfReader.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import ConfReade
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\projects\nodejs\mon-notaire\node_modules\gulp-istanbul\node_modules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:109:37)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at C:\projects\nodejs\mon-notaire\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:192:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How can I prevent these errors from occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up `.babelrc`?

If you're using the latest version of `isparta`, which depends on babel v6, then you need to set up `.babelrc` like the following. ( You also need to do `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` )

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't use babel.rc since I don't use babel command, but gulp one

Comment: `.babelrc` is not only for babel-cli, but it works for all tools depending on babel-core such as babelify, isparta, babel-model of gulp, etc. It doesn't seem documented well but as far as I tried in various environments, it works like that. [This](https://github.com/kt3k/karma-browserify-isparta-example) is my example settings of using karma, browserify and isparta. If I delete `.babelrc`, I get a similar error like the above.

Answer (score 1):

From gulp-istanbul github page.

```
var isparta = require('isparta');
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');

gulp.src('lib/**.js')
  .pipe(istanbul({
    // supports es6
    instrumenter: isparta.Instrumenter
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
Message:
    Unable to parse C:\projects\nodejs\mon-notaire\src\app\core\logger\concrete\ConsoleLogger.js
```

Means that there is a problem in your code in ConsoleLogger.js , so you might want to check that file out.

This Line :

```
C:\projects\nodejs\mon-notaire\src\test\core\TestConfReader.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import ConfReade
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Suggests that you are using ES6, but your gulp task is not transpiling it to ES5 before running it, which is why you are getting the error.

I have made a [yeoman generator](https://github.com/sohamkamani/generator-nm-es6) which creates a project for exactly this purpose (writing nodeJs projects in ES6) and includes code coverage using istanbul with source code mapping. You might want to take a look at that.

Otherwise, here is my [working gulpfile](https://github.com/sohamkamani/three-object-loader/blob/master/gulpfile.js) from that generator.

I use istanbul, along with a module called remap-istanbul.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are using ES6, but the `gulp-istanbul` doesn't support it by default.

Of course, you can write your functions to compile the ES6 codes, but considering you are using `gulp` in this case, IMHO the simplest way you can do is to use [gulp-babel-istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel-istanbul) instead of `gulp-istanbul`, no need to change your code attached above at all.

```
import istanbul from 'gulp-babel-istanbul'
```

And the rest of the code remains the same.